# Error in using system() in Perl

Tags: perl

I am passing a command to windows command prompt using a Perl code. But it is struggling for long time and I could not figure out. Can you please help?

Here is the command line which I am using:

```
cleartool find . -version "version(\main\LATEST)" -exec "cleartool co -nc \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

and here is the error when I write using `system("")`:

```
system(" cleartool find . -version "version(\main\LATEST)" -exec "cleartool co -nc \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\\"" ");


Bareword found where operator expected at test.pl line 9, near "" cleartool find . -version "version"
    (Missing operator before version?)
Backslash found where operator expected at test.pl line 9, near "main\"
String found where operator expected at test.pl line 9, near ")" -exec ""
    (Missing operator before " -exec "?)
Bareword found where operator expected at test.pl line 9, near "" -exec "cleartool"
    (Missing operator before cleartool?)
Backslash found where operator expected at test.pl line 9, near "nc \"
    (Do you need to predeclare nc?)
syntax error at test.pl line 9, near "" cleartool find . -version "version"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Build a string first, print it, and then pass to `system()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
system 'cleartool find . -version "version(\main\LATEST)" -exec "cleartool co -nc "%CLEARCASE_PN%"';
```